# How to debug object model code?

Tags: debugging

Just finished coding an InfoPath form (C#, InfoPath 2010) on my local PC. Also, I copied the Microsoft.SharePoint.dll from the server to my local Windows 7 Enterprise environment with its respective folder structure (14 hive, ISAPI, etc.)

How am I able to debug? How would I go about debugging this? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article helps.

http://nikspatel.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/debug-browser-enabled-infopath-2010-forms-deployed-on-sharepoint-2010-using-visual-studio-2010/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question. You have to be on the machine where SharePoint is installed in order to debug. Simply copying the dll won't do.

The following links should get you started on basic SP debugging:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650703.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231550.aspx